# Web project requires missing web component ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax 3.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, migrate

I Migrate my project to mvc 5.0 and razor engin 3 with [Microsoft Instruction](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

But when open my solution Get this:
[image]

The Web project 'ProjectName' requires missing web components to run with Visual Studio. Would you like to download and install them using the Web Platform Installer now?
(Note: Some components might require restart to take effect.)

ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax 3.0.0.0

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019361/bogus-web-project-requires-missing-web-component-message-for-razor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519776/missing-web-components-error-when-opening-mvc3-project-in-visual-studio-11-bet)

but these answer doesn't help me
I appreciate for any help

**Update:** 
My Project Build Very well and works without any exception with razor 3 and mvc 5 but just **Intellisense doesn't sense** my Typing and coloring my Code

and also when change this line to **Value="2.0.0.0"** in Application web Config file above error vanish and intelisens works fine

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" **value="3.0.0.0"** />
...
</appSettings>
```

**Update**
After some while, now you can user razor 3 on vs 2012. 
[Here you can upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found The Problem, vs 2012 doesn't support it(see update section of this answer)

From [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/10/how-does-vs-determine-which-version-of-razor-engine-to-use-when-editing-razor-webpage-files.aspx)
said:

> Unlike Razor V2 runtime and design time, VS2013 did not GAC these
>   binaries. Instead, the binaries are installed in the project bin
>   folder when corresponding NuGet package is installed, and in
>   “%ProgramFiles (x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0” to support design time.

So we don't have these dlls in above path when upgrade to mvc5 /razor 3

also read [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968304/create-and-run-mvc-5-project-in-vs-2012/19560412#19560412)

**update: now support it** , [update vs from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Answer (score 42):

I had this problem after installing Visual Studio 2012.

What solved for me was installing the Visual Studio Updates:

1. Tools> Extensions And Updates
2. Select "Updates" in the accordion list on the left.
3. Select "Product Updates".
4. Update to the newest version (At the time of writing of this answer it was Update 4)

Comment: thanks but i don't think your soloution belong to my question.

Comment: Why not? I had the exact same problem after I installed VS2012 and MVC5 and tried to open a MVC5 project.

Comment: This answer **is** correct, the tools won't work without Update 4. You *also* need the web tools mentioned in [developerturk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20473069/38360).

Comment: This worked for me as well.  As soon as I updated my VS 2012 to Update 4, my Razor 3.0 references worked.

Answer (score 4):

Solved:
Follow the below steps, It worked for me:
a)Install VS 2012 Update 4 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

b)ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012  Download link Available here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

c) Restart your dev box

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem. VS 2012 support it.

from install setup file [here upgrade for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Comment: You could type write the answer on your own, in my opinion if you want to put just one link it's better to use comments below the question.

Answer (score 1):

For me was installing the `Visual Studio Updates`:

```
Tools> Extensions And Updates
Select "Updates" in the accordion list on the left.
Select "Product Updates".
Update to the newest version
```

(At the time of writing of this answer it was `Update 4`)