# How to fix json.net (Newtonsoft.Json) runtime file load exception

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, fileloadexception

I get the following exception every time I run my project:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried almost every solution I could find on the web.

My **packages.config** file:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />

and this in web.config file:
 <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" PublicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"  />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="5.0.8"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

I even used the following commands to update/reinstall *json.net*:

```
update-package Newtonsoft.Json -reinstall
update-package Newtonsoft.Json
```

What else I can try?

Comment: I am not sure but it did not work either.

Comment: I just checked, for Json.NET 8.0.2 `typeof(JsonSerializer).Assembly.FullName` has `Version=8.0.0.0`.  So give that one a try.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685530/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-or-one-of-its-dependencies-ma.  Of course the version number is inappropriate for Json.NET 8.0.2 in that answer.

Comment: You are right about the version number, I got this message when I try to reinstall:

Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2' to Prodb1.
But the exception still coming up in running time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found the problem. I did not add  culture="neutral" when I put this in web.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" PublicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"  />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your binding redirect newVersion and oldVersion to match the version of Json.net your are trying to use:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" PublicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"  />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

4.5 is the framework version, not the version of Json.net

Comment: I still have the exception. Does this have anything to do with this message ?
 File visual studio 2013\Projects\Prodb1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.2\tools\install.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: Still with the additional information, or has it changed at all?

Comment: Are you able to share your code as a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment I can't recreate your exact scenario locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and upon closer inspection I realized that somehow Newtonsoft had gotten added twice as a

```
<dependentAssembly>..</dependentAssembly>
```

in my web.config file.  I had version 8.0 and 9.0 entries.  I believe the 2nd entry was created when I updated from 8.0 to 9.0.  A new entry was automatically created, however the old entry was not removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue holding up I just installed the Nuget Package 'Newtonsoft.json', for my project. And it get solved