# Could not load file or assembly 'GMap.NET.Core, Version=1.7.5.0

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I am trying to load a map on my project. I'm using `WPF` on my project but since I can't use the "Overlays" I'm using to put a marker, and it's working on WindowsForm, I am now using it and calling it to the WPF form, until I encountered this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'GMap.NET.Core, Version=1.7.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b85b9027b614afef' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I look in my references, and I only have a reference to `GMap.NET.Core` version 1.7.0.0.
Can anybody please help me should I solve this?

Comment: Please Check versions of assemblies used in your projects in solution & use single version,see the appconfig file.

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="GMap.NET.Core" publicKeyToken="b85b9027b614afef" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.5.0" newVersion="1.7.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

this is what on my appconfig file. i've already change the version I'm using. but it still show the same error.

Comment: I have edited my answer please kindly review again hope this will help.

Comment: what version of .Net are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to just download the project of Gmap.Net from [here](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) next extract the project files open Release-NETv(any_version)

this contain assembly of Gmap.Net.Core  ,so just add reference of this assembly in your project.

Here is what happens when assemblies not matches this is not same problem but will help you understand.

**Example Of Incorrect Reference**

[image: Reference]

**Error**

[image: Reference Error]

**Solution**

To solve this kindly open your app config file and see the version number of gmap package there then check the version number of gmap inside your references if they not match delete dll from references and change the version number to 1.7.5.0 in your appconfig then rebuild project visual studio automatically restore the missing assemblies so they will be same on both sides
For your better understanding please look this screen shot when I have an assembly in references uses version which is less the version is being use in project appconfig.
When you install a package from package manager it goes inside package folder of your application to add this,delete the reference from references if contain old version then add latest version from package folder.

**Error Solve**

By changing the version in appconfig the error was gone.

[image]

Comment: I've tried using that, both version. But still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

3 yers later lol

replace this value on app.config

`Example`  assemblyIdentity name="GMap.NET.Core" publicKeyToken="b85b9027b614afef" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.5.0" newVersion="1.7.5.0"