# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.json Version 6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, .net-assembly

I am trying to update the NewtonSoft to it's latest addition 11.0.1 but when I updated the Dll using NuGet Manager then it started givng me this Error I even Deleted files from all the Temp folders that could be there for the ASP.NEt FrameWork but it seems not to be going away.

```
  Error:
Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

What else can I try doing here?

Comment: In your `web.config` file, is there anything related to Newtonsoft? E.g. `BindingRedirect`s?

Comment: Try reinstalling the package again. The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685530/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-or-one-of-its-dependencies-ma) would help.

Comment: Ok I will try Re-Installing it also yes there is a BindingRedirect I found in the Web.config It shows that the OLD version is set to 0-6 and newVersion is set to 11.0.1 but still gives the Error

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the solution usually fixes this error for me