# Installing UCommerce on Sitefinity and it Throws NewtonSoft.json Error

Tags: sitefinity

So, Here is the actual issue. I have created a sitefinity project through Sitefinity Project Manager and after running it, i open the project files into my visual Studio 2019. I checked till here that everything is working fine and it was. Now when i go for installing Ucommerce on the project through Nuget packages. The package is Ucommerce.Sitefinity after installation it simply throws this error whenver i run it. Even when i removed the package the problem was still there.
Its like the Ucommerce package corrupts the project completely.[image: I have attached the screenshot for better explanation.]. I have tried resolving it by searching on the internet but somehow it seems the solutions which worked for others are not for me as my project is not a simple asp.net project rather a sitefinity project, I may be wrong. Most of the solutions which i tried are from this thread here : [Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. Manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685530/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-or-one-of-its-dependencies-ma) But as i said all in vain. Please help me with this as i need to get started with my development on the ucommerce for a project. Thanks in advance.
Also After removing the nuget package the Values for the Version changed from 6.0.0.0 to 12.0.0.0 .

Comment: What version of Ucommerce and what version of Sitefinity ? Since you asked this question two days ago in a fresh installation I assume you tried installing on Sitefinity 13 ? This is currently not supported by Ucommerce but will be in a months time or so.

Comment: Actually i was able to fix this problem. The package for NewtonSoft.json was at 10v so i needed to update it to 12.0 v. Once i did that the problem resolved and it was working as it needs to. What i did i run the nuget package manager and update the Newtonsoft.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually deleting all files from the bin folder and then build again.

Probably there was an assembly that referenced an old version of the newtonsoft dll.

Finally, check the runtime bindings in web.config for the version of newtonsoft dll there.
Make sure it points to the version that is inside your packages.config file.

Comment: I actually tried to delete the bin folder in hope that i can fix the different version issue for NewronSoft.json but that didn't work. However updating the NewtonSoft.json from the Nuget package Manager worked for me so i think that could be a potential solution. Thanks for the answer.